# Deployment issue of windows form application with ms access on client laptop

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, ms-access

i have created an inventory system using C# Windows form application[vs 2013 and framework 4] and MS Access database[ms office 2013] 
it's running on my computer well
but when i deploy on client pc it fails to run
i have install db engine and old framework also on clieent laptop but same problem
Thanks In Regard
 i am facing this problem[ScreenShot] on client laptop 
[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhQfD.jpg)

Comment: check the version of db engine installed

Comment: i mean either 32 bit or 64 bit, check it with OS

Comment: i have installs 32 bit version of db engine on client laptop,because when i install 64 bit version on his laptop it saying that u have 32 bit office so u cant install 64 bit db engine

Comment: is your office contain Microsoft Access ?

Comment: yeah access installed on his laptop as well but i don't know why this happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1 :

In your application under Menu Project \ Properties \
under tab Compile change Traget CPU into X86.
Under Menu Build\Configuration manager \Active solution plateFrome >X86

Solution 2 :

NOTE: this DOES work for office 2010 even though it is for 2007 office, dont ask me why it just does :)

1. download and install this: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23734
2. in VS click add data source, follow the wizard .

More links :
- 1 [link 1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb)

Comment: with pleasure. :) can you vote up the answer please .Thanks also

Comment: I am sorry m new here so my reputation here is below 15 so i can't give u vote right now

Comment: Ok no probleme ,so i do that for your i vote up you question . :)